# Divide a number into unique random numbers in PHP

Tags: php

referring to an old question about  [Divide a single number into a set of unique random numbers in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40088263/divide-a-single-number-into-a-set-of-unique-random-numbers-in-php)

Thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/users/1545088/matei-mihai for the code

```
  function generateRandomNumbers($max, $count){
        $numbers = [];

        for ($i = 1; $i < $count; $i++) {
            $random = mt_rand(0, $max / ($count - $i));
            $numbers[] = $random;
            $max -= $random;
        }
        $numbers[] = $max;
        shuffle($numbers);
        return $numbers;
    }
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r(generateRandomNumbers(100, 10));
    echo '</pre>';
```

With the coding above, how can I have results without any of them having zero (0)?

Update: if I change $max = 10 and $count = 20 (generateRandomNumbers(10, 20)), I would like to have results with decimal except 0 (zero)

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2
    [1] => 0
    [2] => 1
    [3] => 2
    [4] => 0
    [5] => 1
    [6] => 0
    [7] => 0
    [8] => 0
    [9] => 0
    [10] => 0
    [11] => 0
    [12] => 1
    [13] => 0
    [14] => 3
    [15] => 0
    [16] => 0
    [17] => 0
    [18] => 0
    [19] => 0
)
```

Is there anyway by using these values generateRandomNumbers(10, 20) and having results without zero but with decimal instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this set of code

```
 function random_float($min, $max) {
  return random_int($min, $max - 1) + (random_int(0, PHP_INT_MAX - 1) / PHP_INT_MAX );
}

function generateRandomNumbers($max, $count){
$randoms = [];

    for ($i=0; $i <$count ; $i++) {
      if($i>0)
      {
        while(1){
          $this_random = random_float(0.1,$max);
          if(!in_array($this_random,$randoms))
          {
            $randoms[] = $this_random;
            break;
          }
        }
      }
      else {
        $this_random = random_float(0.1,$max);
        $randoms[] = $this_random;
      }
    }
    $numbers = [];
    $sum_of_randoms = array_sum($randoms);
    foreach ($randoms as $key => $value) {
      $numbers[] = ($value/$sum_of_randoms) * $max;
    }
    return $numbers;
  }


echo array_sum(generateRandomNumbers(10,20));
echo '<pre>';
print_r(generateRandomNumbers(10,20));
echo '</pre>';
```

I have now updated the code which makes an array of specific floated random numbers have sum of the `$max`. You can test the code live [here](https://3v4l.org/IKhOJ)

Comment: Thanks. is there anyway to have decimal for example generateRandomNumbers(10, 20) which means each will have number with decimal unequally results

Comment: Can you explain it more? What did you mean `0.5 equally`

Comment: im sorry, i mean with decimal.

Comment: Thanks for the updated code but it will have infinity loop when i use generateRandomNumbers(10, 20). if $count is greater than $max, it will have infinity loop

Comment: Hmm you are right. I have made it for `generateRandomNumbers(100, 10)`

Comment: Please wait.. I am checking it

Comment: Ok got it.. please wait

Comment: the results is not total 10. :(

Comment: Sorry.. I thought that in `generateRandomNumbers(10,20)` min is 10 and max is 20 as I am busy in many other things. I have updated now :)

Comment: appreciate your time but i think its not correct as well. In summary, i wanted to divide sum of 10 into 20 unique numbers without having zero (obviously will have decimals) as answer by having sum up 10. which means $max =10 and $count = 20 =  generateRandomNumbers(10,20).

Comment: Ok.. I have got the solution but sometimes it also gives the negative value

Comment: like this `Array
(
 [0] => 0.053294512468062
 [1] => 0.0037014610151301
 [2] => 0.4871735039573
 [3] => 0.89928049868871
 [4] => 0.65275425168348
 [5] => 0.86222929454512
 [6] => 0.63991706382479
 [7] => 0.28888641870063
 [8] => 0.93154974837394
 [9] => 0.67205329922589
 [10] => 0.83329342344463
 [11] => 0.62663644022617
 [12] => 0.23574839776184
 [13] => 0.78511557019554
 [14] => 0.2863850841701
 [15] => 0.077011352906475
 [16] => 0.32339949501837
 [17] => 0.62427152582643
 [18] => 0.77165179176799
 [19] => -0.054353133800605
)`

Comment: here last one is negative

Comment: hmm that defeat the whole purpose. still looking for solution by dividing 10 into 20 random numbers by not having zero as results. this could be a challenge.

Comment: Please wait. I am making another algo

Comment: Updated the better version now. It will give you an array of unique random numbers which will be the sum of `$max`

Answer (score 0):

You must use this code block.

```
  function generaenter code hereteRandomNumbers($max, $count){
        $numbers = [];

        for ($i = 1; $i < $count; $i++) {
            $random = mt_rand(1, $max / ($count - $i));
            $numbers[] = $random;
            $max -= $random;
        }
        $numbers[] = $max;
        shuffle($numbers);
        return $numbers;
    }
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r(generateRandomNumbers(100, 10));
    echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: Anyway to generate with this values generateRandomNumbers(10, 20) with having decimals in results?